# Why doesn't ENTER work in some Save-File dialogs?

Tags: windows, firefox, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

tl;dr

In Save-File dialogs, keyboard input like Enter and ALT-S (to save) either won't work, requiring mouse input, or they're require a confusing 8-10 presses till they finally go through, oddly. There doesn't seem to be any sort of rhyme, reason, or pattern as to why this happens. And it's happened over the years across computers and reformats.

Any ideas why?

For the record, I don't have any third party programs that are hooking these keyboard shortcuts, and this would definitely be apparent with a bottom-floor "shortcut" like "Enter". It also wouldn't explain why these keyboard inputs *can* eventually go through in an open file dialog, it just takes a certain number of presses. It's not a busy CPU/time delay problem, either, where the CPU is trying to keep up.

**EXPLANATION:**

When a save file dialog opens, being a keyboard warrior, I try to save it out without needing the mouse. Because the filename input is focused by default (and filename text pre-selected), all that should be necessary is a simple press of Enter. Sometimes this works on the first try, saving and closing the dialog.

Sometimes, however -- often even -- it takes 8-10+ presses of Enter until it eventually, randomly saves. It's not just Enter, either, but also the ALT-letter shortcuts (my personal preference). I'll have to mash ALT-S just as many times until it works. But sometimes the ALT-letter shortcuts won't work, period, leaving it to Enter 8-10+ times or having to use the mouse. And sometimes even Enter doesn't work, forcing me to resort to the mouse.

I thought maybe something was hooking input, like another program taking over a shortcut, but the fact that it doesn't work with multiple ALT-letters, and most of all, another program not being able to hook Enter away without it being immediately apparent. And I've never seen any intermittent, sporadic hookings of keyboard input.

**EXAMPLE 1:**

Here in my browser (Firefox), just above, I just right-clicked the Superuser logo and pressed 'V' to save image. The save dialog opens. Filename input/text is focused + selected. I leave it as the default and press ALT-S to save. Nothing. I mash it 10+ times. Nothing. I try Enter. Nothing. I press Enter 8-10 times, and it finally works. Starting over, I try tabbing out of the input box and then ALT-shortcutting, to no avail, thinking maybe tabbing might break whatever is interfering with or taking over the input focus.

**EXAMPLE 2:**

I just opened Notepad in Windows, then ALT-F-A to Save-as. I press Enter. Immediate save. This works repeatedly, first press, every time. When trying with the ALT-letter shortcuts instead, I get nothing. Doesn't work at all, ever. Thinking maybe the textbox input wasn't letting go of letter-input, I tab once to get out of it and then try ALT-S. Nothing.

Curiously, if I tab away from the filename textbox, the ALT-shortcut to jump back to it, ALT-N, and file type, both work fine, every time. But never ALT-S, no matter what subsequent element is tabbed to, even when it's on the Save button itself. Pressing 'S' on the Save button works.

So it's as if something is hooking ALT-S, however, it sometimes works in Firefox.

Stumped.

Comment: I have the same issue too, so I'll be keeping an eye on this.